# How to handle code migration when working with Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to understand the best way to migrate code when working with Snowflake. There are two scenarios, one where we have only one snowflake account and that houses all environments (dev, test, prod). And the other has two accounts (non-prod, prod). With the second option, I was planning to create a separate script that will set up the correct database name which is based on environment (dev_ent_dw, prod_ent_dw) and then I will refer these as variables when creating objects. Example -

```
set env = ‘dev’;
set db = $env || ‘_ent_dw.’;
```

Right now we’re running everything manually so the devops team will run these upfront before running ddl scripts. We may do something similar with the former scenario but I am wondering if folks can share best practices of dealing with this as I am sure it would be common topic at large enterprises.

Answer (score 0):

We have different accounts for each environment (dev, qa, prod).  We use Azure DevOps for change management within our team, including the Git repos and Azure Pipelines for deploying scripts via [schemachange](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange).

We do NOT append an environment to objects, as that is handled by the account.
Developers write migration scripts and check them into source control.  We then create Version folders and move/rename the migration scripts for deployment, and run a pipeline to execute the changes.  The only thing we need to change is the URL to deploy against, and that is handled within the pipeline itself.  The nice thing here is that we do not need to tweak anything going from different branches in source control.

We have not been doing much with creating clones for development work, as we usually only have one developer working on changes to a set of objects at a time.  We are exploring ways to improve our process, but what we have works fairly well for our current needs.